What is the safest way to take down a person in a street fight?
What is the safest way to take down a person in street fight with just one strike?
Punching to face, abdomen, pushing to the floor could be too much damages if the person died , blind or severely harm. Most cases in my country, it doesn't count as self defense.
I would think just a Muay Thai low kick to this area? What is the maximum damage to this?


I think this is too complex a question to ask, and too opinionated. Tying "physical safety" of an opponent in with "legally safe", and then also considering what is practical and effective self-defense and fighting, it's just too difficult a question to give a good answer to. You'll get either very lengthy discussions of each category, or you'll get a blanket statement saying there is no effective answer to your question. It's not possible to control what happens to someone you strike and keep them safe. The safest but still unsafe technique? Opinion. Too many variables.

I broadly agree with Steve, but I think that the biggest issue here is you are asking for a Just one strike solution.  Real life isn't like that.  The easiest way to keep you enemy safe is to grapple them rather than strike, but there are other issues with this strategy.

@SteveWeigand what about this https://www.facebook.com/share/r/DyvMeR3vJRA9cVXE/  ? Can't think anything better

@whatsappcat That's showing a sanda boxing drill kicking out the legs of someone who is moving. You have a problem in that this involves a fall. No matter how you do it, it can still land someone on their head and kill them. The sanda boxers in this video knew what was coming and were trained to break the fall with their hands and arms. Untrained people would not necessarily know how to break the fall. This is also a difficult and precise move that is unlikely to result in success in most situations. I can't say this is any better or worse than anything else with regards to safety.

@Steve Weigand  the knee or butt should land first? how can be the head ? hmm  ..

@HuwEvans grapple ? u heard of this story?https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-52806572    any head lock eventually quite dangerous

@whatsappcat There are two kicks shown. First one does land the guy on his butt. That could easily land him on the back of his head if this is an untrained fighter. Second kick is landing him on his face / forehead. It's just that he's able to do the breakfall to save himself. Even trained fighters often get taken by surprise and don't land well from these. If you kick with more force in that first kick example, the upper body rotates, and it can very easily land him on the back of his head. This was a drill / demo, so it was more controlled.

@Steve Weigand I guess the 2nd kick would be safer.. normal human reflection will block with hand before falling down to protect the forehead.. even my turtle can do.. hmm  .. just a step back and sweep. Well, still have very low possibility the person so dumb fall straight, hit the forehead and died.

@whatsappcat A front fall is "safer" in the sense that you might reasonably rely on a person's instincts to use his hands to stop the fall. That is an instinct people tend to have. I do want to mention, though, that the inside foot sweep can easily cause someone to fall backwards as well. Real life doesn't go as planned most of the time. To help with safety, you want to control the fall. That requires learning grappling. Judo in particular. Only then can you control someone while throwing them. A good judo practitioner can land someone on their back safely or on their head fatally.

@Steve Weigand how can attacker punch with body forward and fall backwards after a front leg sweep from a defender?

@whatsappcat The only way to ensure an attacker falls forward during an inside leg sweep is to grab them from their back and pull them forward. Otherwise, it's more likely they will fall diagonally backwards (back and to the side). Even just being in front of them means you are an obstruction to them falling forward. The natural inclination is for them to fall backwards and to the side in an inside leg sweep. I'm saying it's 50/50 whether they'll fall forward or backward, and it depends on your skill and experience whether or not you can cause them to do either.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I’m voting to close this question because it tries to argue that the OP's initial opinion is right, and hence is not asked in good faith. The OP is debating and defending an unreasonable (from an expert viewpoint) opinion with the use of fallacies like reductio ad rediculum. Without the will to learn from and trust in experts, this is not a useful question to have here.
